# Как добавить ещё одно действие для конкретного вызова одной и той же функции?

Tags: javascript, функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта функция будет вызываться несколько раз. И лишь в одном случае мне нужно выполнить дополнительное действие. Это условие не срабатывает.

Как мне из множества вызовов этой функции добавить ещё одно действие для конкретного случая?

```
function calcPriceHeight(elementChange) {
    let heightArray = [];

    // check each elem height including padding
    elementChange.each( function () {
        let elemHeight = $(this).innerHeight()
        heightArray.push(elemHeight);
    });

    //put all heights into array
    let array = $.map(heightArray, function(value){
        return [value];
    });

    // apply to all same elements same height
    elementChange.css({'minHeight' : Math.max.apply(Math, array)})


    if (elementChange === $(".s-package-slider-price-top .s-package-slider-price-block")) {
        $('.s-package-slider-row-titles').css({'paddingTop' : Math.max.apply(Math, array)})
    }
}

calcPriceHeight($(".s-package-slider-price-top .s-package-slider-price-block"))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте код текстом, а не изображением, чтобы отвечающим было легче копировать и тестировать фрагменты.

Comment: Может, вам добавить второй параметр в функцию для подобных исключительных вызовов и использовать его, чтобы их отличать?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, условие сравнения в вашем случае не работает потому, что объект, переданный в функцию, и объект, создаваемый в проверке с тем же селектором, — это два разных объекта, хоть и с одним содержимым, ведь объекты сравниваются не по содержимому, а по идентичности, и `{} !== {}`.

Comment: Добавил кодом. Редко сюда захожу, забываю о правилах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов `$(".class-1 .class-2")` возвращает специальный jQuery-объект элементов, через `===` он никогда не будет равен никакому другому значению.

Проверять jQuery-элемент на соответствие с селектором, можно так:

`if ( elementChange.is(".class-1 .class-2") ) { ...`

Вернет true, если у `elementChange` есть `class-2`, а он сам находится где-то внутри `class-1`

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  console.log( $(e.target).is(".a .b") );
});
```

```css
.a { background: #169; padding: 20px; }
.b { background: #f70; padding: 30px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a">
  <div class="b">

  </div>
</div>
```

---

А в стандартном JS есть `.matches()`

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log( e.target.matches(".a .b") );
});
```

```css
.a { background: #169; padding: 20px; }
.b { background: #f70; padding: 30px; }
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь сравнить два массива, не два объекта, а они никогда не будут равны.
Нужно изменить на что-то подобное.

```
if (elementChange[0] === $(".s-package-slider-price-top .s-package-slider-price-block")[0])
```

P/S jQuery селектор возвращает не DOM элемент, а массив элементов. Если элементов больше одного, то нужно будет уже сравнивать каждый из элементов.

Comment: Напишите `console.log( $("body") )` - не очень похож на массив) Хоть и содержит числовые ключи и свойство length.